# First Polish letter in the name of image is cut once uploading to Wordpress [preg_replace]

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

Once I upload an image to WordPress, I have the function that is putting the name of the file in fields: ALT, TITLE, CAPTION. I expect to have those fields populated the same as it in the file name.

The code:

```
    add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {
if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {
$my_image_title = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;
$my_image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ', $my_image_title );
$my_image_meta = array(
'ID' => $post_ID,
'post_title' => $my_image_title,
'post_content' => $my_image_title,
'post_excerpt' => $my_image_title,
);
update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt',
$my_image_title );
wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );
}
}
```

Can you please tell me why once:

- file name is "Śnieżka" then it comes in Wordpress "nieżka"
- however once file name is "Snieżka" then it comes in Wordpress "Snieżka" correctly?

**Polish letter is not accepted, once it is the first one in the name.**

Thank you for help.
Jakub

Comment: I recommend using English letters for file names. Otherwise you might get gibberish file names when migrating to another server.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I am running Polish-English website and need to have also Polish letters and wording.

Comment: You might try urlencode for the filenames, typically non english characters in filenames are invalid.

Comment: @HowardE can you please tell me how I can adapt the code for this?